# Locating libdbodbc.so for Sybase on linux

Tags: database, unix, odbc, sybase, unixodbc

I'm trying to connect to Sybase database from the web server using UnixODBC. 
Sybase is installed on windows server while the web server is on Unix Server.

In order to connect to Sybase I'm using UnixODBC which requires the file libdbodbc.so for Sybase I'm trying to locate this file but I'm unable to find it anywhere.

Anyone can tell me where can i find it or can help providing it to me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Installing FreeTDS will install the libtdsodbc.so library. Typical install location is /user/lib with configuration files in /usr/etc and /usr/etc/freetds.

See the following links for configuration info:

http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS.html

http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/linux.html

Answer (score 0):

have you tried locate ?

```
locate libdbodbc.so
```

*EDIT*: maybe you have to update the locate database (as root) with

```
updatedb
```

Comment: you propably already now this, but just in case you don't: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35456.1550/pdf/ocspsunx.pdf

Comment: Thanks. 
the problem is i can't compile the so since the Sybase on windows. 
Looks like i have to find someone with sybase on unix to get the file from him.